# itamae で inventory を管理するには?

Tags: itamae

Ansible では inventory によって、どのホストに対して何の role を実行するかを管理できますが、そのようなことを itamae 管理したい場合に、これはどのように実現されますか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[kondate](https://github.com/sonots/kondate) が、ちょうどその機能を提供する様子です。

`/hosts.yml` に、「ホスト: ロールたち」の形式で記述した後に、

```
bundle exec kondate itamae host
```

すると、 `recipes/roles/#{role}.yml` の role が実行される様子です。